# Ĉu ekzistas libera Esperanta kurso?

Tags: course

Ĉu ekzistas libera Esperanta kurso?

Mi serĉas liberajn (CC-by[-sa] ≥ 3) kursojn de Esperanto en Esperanto por komenci plenigi la lingvan fakon de [Vikiklerigejo](https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do) (alinomita Vikiversitato kaj vikia universitato).

Comment: De Esperanto en Esperanto - cxu nur-Esperanta kurso?

Comment: Mi ne certas ke mi komprenas vian demandon. Vikiklerigejo estas generala deponejo de kursoj, ne nur kurso pri Esperanto, se tio estas via demando. Do, al aliaj liberaj kursoj ni diras bonvenon. Sed tie mia demando estas specife

Comment: [erare tro frue publikigis la antaŭa mesaĝo] kurso pri Esperanto, kiu estas verkita esperante. Do oni povus uzi unue tiu kurso de Esperanto, kaj poste legi aliajn. Memoru ke Vikimediaj projecktoj egale estas konsultebla senrete, ekzemple kun [Kiwix](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiwix) aŭ por uloj kun limita aliro al interreto , ekzemple kun [Wikipedia Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Zero).

Answer (score 6):

[La Esperanto-kurso laŭ la Zagreba metodo](https://github.com/Esperanto/kurso-zagreba-metodo) ŝajnis interesa, sed la permesilo por la teksto estas mallibera (CC-by-**ND**).

Ankaŭ ekzistas la programaro [kurso de esperanto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurso_de_Esperanto), kiu estas licenca laŭ GPL. Sed ŝajnas ke [la fontkodo](http://kurso.com.br/kurso.amd64.tar.gz) ne indikas la licencon por la lerna materialo, kaj [la oficiala retpaĝaro](http://www.kurso.com.br/index.php?eo) ne diras plu, aŭ mi mankis la informon.

La Angla Wikibooks havas [liberan verkon](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Esperanto), kaj egale [Wikiversity proponas kursojn angle](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Esperanto).

Answer (score 6):

- [Open of Course Esperanto Course](http://www.open-of-course.org/courses/mod/page/view.php?id=665) is released under a a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 2.5 License.
- [Intro to Esperanto by Rachel J. Morris](http://www.moosader.com/lessons/IntroToEsperanto1_Moosader.pdf) is released under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.
- [The Esperanto teacher](https://www.merlot.org/merlot/viewMaterial.htm?id=826648) is available under an Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 United States.
- [Primary Esperanto Beginner Materials by Penelope Vos](https://cnx.org/exports/83f2c83c-67b0-45b9-be10-b5fee38539f7@1.1.pdf/primary-esperanto-beginner-materials-1.1.pdf) are released under a CC attribution 3.0 license.

I'm still not super familiar with these licenses, but I hope it helps!
The more courses available, the better.

I'm not sure how to categorize [Kurso de Esperanto](http://9k.9941.yi.org/0/?url=b3RuYXJlcHNFX2VkX29zcnVLL2lraXcvZ3JvLmFpZGVwaWtpdy5uZS8vQTMlc3B0dGg=), which is available under a GPLv3 license.

Bedaŭrinde mi pensas ke preskaŭ ĉiuj estas en la angla…

Ne estas kurso, sed ne forgesu ke ankaŭ libroj estas haveblaj tiel: [La Marvirinstrato](https://www.amazon.ca/Marvirinstrato-Originalaj-noveloj-en-Esperanto/dp/1439236348), ekzemple.

> Marvirinstrato de Tim Westover estas havebla sub la Creative Commons
>   Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivative Works 3.0 United States
>   License. Vi rajtas libere uzi kaj represi la novelojn el tiu ĉi
>   novelaro en via klubo, **kurso**, podkasto, radioelsendo, bulteno aŭ
>   periodaĵo laŭ la kondiĉoj de la permesilo Creative Commons.

Comment: Dankon, Lyubomir!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. CC-*-nc are not free license, so while the linked material might be useful for some people, they are not for the purpose of adding a course on project like Wikiversity where only free/libre license can be used. The course of Penelope Vos seemed very interesting, but as far as I was able to find, it doesn't contains anything except some metadata details. I was already aware of _Kurso de Esperanto_, I'm waiting an email answer from them. Maybe _Intro to Esperanto by Rachel J. Morris _ may fit, I will look at that possibly  validate your answer accordingly, tnank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jen unu:

https://youtu.be/RnCxBvUCFTg

En la priskribo oni diras ke la kurso estas CC BY-SA 3.0

Answer (score 0):

La ejo ‘Ekonomia Bulteno pri Usono’, rekte kaj libere atingebla, havas strikte paralelajn tekstojn angla – Esperanta. Jen la ligilo al ĝi:

https://ekonomiabultenopriusono.com/

La paralela formato de la traduko havas du celojn:

1. faciligi lingve-kontroli la tradukon;
   kaj
2. esti rimedo por lernantoj de la angla.